# Wrap text in table column with \textwidth, \multicolumn and \multirow in LaTeX

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow, textwidth

I'm looking to wrap the text in the 3rd column, so that the table doesn't render too small (and disproportionate) on my document. Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|cc|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Species}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Strain}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Resistance mechanisms (if applicable)}}       & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Insecticide / n bioassays (n mosquitoes)} \\ \cline{4-5} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Chlorfenapyr}         & Tralopyril        \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\textit{An   coluzzii}}        & Banfora                                      & Kdr995F, Kdr1570Y, Rdl296S                                                        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6 (420)}              &                   \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                               & Tiefora                                      & Kdr995F, Kdr1570Y, Rdl296G, CYP6P4                                                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6 (422)}              &                   \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                               & VK7-2014                                     & Kdr995F, Kdr1570Y, Rdl296G, CYP6M2,   CYP6P3, CYP6P4, CYP6Z1, GSTE2               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6 (412)}              & 6 (421)           \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textit{An   funestus}}        & FANG                                         & Susceptible                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6 (416)}              &                   \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                               & FUMOZ-R                                      & CYP6P9A, CYP6P9B                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6 (412)}              &                   \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\textit{An gambiae}}           & Bakaridjan                                   & Kdr995F, Kdr1570Y, Rdl296G, CYP9K1,   CYP6M2, CYP6P4                              & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9 (621)}              &                   \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                               & Gauora-a ra                                  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Kdr995F, Kdr995S, Rdl296S,\\    \\ CYP6Z1\end{tabular} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{9 (413)}              & 9 (650)           \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                               & Kisumu                                       & Susceptible                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6 (401)}              & 9 (660)           \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                               & Tiassalé-13                                  & Kdr995F, Ace-1, CYP6M2, CYP6P3, CYP6P4,   CYP6Z1                                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{6 (426)}              &                   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Which produces the following table:
[image]

Any help/tips appreciated!!

Comment: Using a p column or \parbox would make the number of rows (`\baselineskip`) change, depending on content.  You can still use `\multirow`, but you will have to adjust the number of rows.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please do tell us (a) which document class you employ, (b) what the main document font size is, and (c) how wide the textblock is -- or, alternatively, how wide the margins are.

Comment: never use `\resizebox` on tables, as you see it will always produce inconsisitent font sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow automatic line breaking not only in the cells of column 3, but also in the header that spans columns 4 and 5. Instead of employing a `tabular` environment, I suggest you use a [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) environment, with a target width of `\textwidth` and the `X` column type in use for column 3.

I can't see a good use for the multitude of `\multirow` and `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{...}` [pun intended] wrappers. Get rid of them. I'd further get rid of all vertical rules since they aren't needed and won't be missed. And I would not, repeat: *not*, employ the `\resizebox` sledgehammer.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} % or some other suitable document class and font size

%\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed

\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'X' col. type and 'tabularx' environment
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % disable full justification

% Calculate usable width of combination of columns 4 and 5:
\newlength\mylen 
\settowidth\mylen{ChlorfenapyrTralopyril} % longest words in cols 4 and 5
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr\mylen+2\tabcolsep\relax}}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{Bugs, bugs, and more bugs\strut} % set as needed

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} ll L cc @{}}
\toprule
Species & Strain & Resistance mechanisms (if applicable) & 
  \multicolumn{2}{C@{}}{Insecticide\slash $n$ bioassays ($n$ mosquitoes)} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){4-5} 
 & & & Chlorfenapyr & Tralopyril  \\ 
\midrule
\textit{An coluzzii} & Banfora & Kdr995F, Kdr1570Y, Rdl296S & 6 (420) & \\ 
\addlinespace 
& Tiefora & Kdr995F, Kdr1570Y, Rdl296G, CYP6P4 & 6 (422) & \\ 
\addlinespace 
& VK7-2014 & Kdr995F, Kdr1570Y, Rdl296G, CYP6M2, CYP6P3, CYP6P4, CYP6Z1, GSTE2 & 6 (412) & 6 (421) \\ 
\addlinespace
\textit{An funestus} & FANG & Susceptible & 6 (416)  & \\ 
\addlinespace 
& FUMOZ-R  & CYP6P9A, CYP6P9B & 6 (412) & \\ 
\addlinespace
\textit{An gambiae} & Bakaridjan & Kdr995F, Kdr1570Y, Rdl296G, CYP9K1, CYP6M2, CYP6P4 & 9 (621) & \\ 
\addlinespace 
& Gauora-a ra  & Kdr995F, Kdr995S, Rdl296S, CYP6Z1 & 9 (413) & 9 (650) \\ 
\addlinespace 
& Kisumu   & Susceptible & 6 (401) & 9 (660) \\ 
\addlinespace 
& Tiassalé-13 & Kdr995F, Ace-1, CYP6M2, CYP6P3, CYP6P4, CYP6Z1 & 6 (426) & \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you - that worked great!